# The appellation

Tags: polynomials

The degree of a polynomial is the highest degree of its terms when the polynomial is expressed in its canonical form consisting of a linear combination of monomial and The radian is the standard unit of angular measure, used in many areas of mathematics. The length of an arc of a unit circle is numerically equal to the measurement in radians of the angle that it subtends; one radian is just under 57.3 degrees when the arc length is equal to the radius

What is relation between degree of polynomials and degree equal $\pi /180$

Comment: None :-) This is fun !!!

Comment: The degrees Fahrenheit of boiling water could also play a rôle here.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter Don't forget bachelor's, master's, and doctoral degrees.

Answer (score 0):

The same relation as the fact that the water boils at 100 degree and a right angle is 90 degree.... The word '' degree'' is used with completely different and unrelated meanings.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of overworked terms in mathematics that have many unrelated meanings.  "Degree" is one of them.  but is far from the worst offender.  Try "normal".

Answer (score 0):

If there were a relation, and if it such relations were transitive, then considering that degrees of an arc can be converted to [seconds of an arc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minute_and_second_of_arc), and seconds on the clock measure time, it would follow that polynomial degrees have the dimension of time.

P.S. Sorry, I was just joking. There is no relation except [homonymy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homonym).